# Google Maps controls changed their look, how can I get them back?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

A few months ago the Google Maps v3 controls had a nice CSS# polished look. Now they look horrible (see attached pic). I don't think I did anything that would change their look. How can I get them back? Has anybody else encountered this behaviour?

[image: Old look vs new look]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened after release of 3.7 version of Maps JS API: if you look into [changelog](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog), there are line:  `New visual style of default controls`.

Assuming you didn't know the fact and don't use some new functionality, you can specify previous version of api when loading libraries, use similar url in script tag or as params with google js loader:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=true_or_false
```

[API Versioning](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Versioning)

Comment: It's always good to put the version number on anyway, in case a recent change to the API causes problems (can sometimes happen).  As they say on that API page: "Production applications should always specify a minor version (eg. 3.5, 3.6, etc.)."

Comment: It, indeed, helped. I looked everywhere I knew. It never came to my mind that there is a changelog where I could look.